# Liferay submit a form with ajax

Tags: liferay

I'm trying to post a form in Liferay with jQuery Ajax (I prefer don't use Alloy).

I tried two ways

1-

```
jQuery.post("<%=responsesURL%>",jQuery("#responsesForm").serialize());
```

2-

```
jQuery.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "<%=responsesURL%>",
         data: jQuery("#responsesForm").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
         success: function(data)
         {
            console.log(data);
         }
       });
```

The form is

```
<form name="responsesForm" id="responsesForm" action='<%=responsesURL%>' method="POST">
<input .....>
</form>
```

I guess that the serialize is not working properly when I try request the data with

```
ParamUtil.getString(request, "resp167-1")
```

But is empty!

I don't know what can I do.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Well you can check what is being sent in FireBug (or other browser dev tools).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a portlet namespace:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet"%>

<portlet:defineObjects />

<form ...>
    <input name="<portlet:namespace />resp167-1" />
    ...
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about that, was a code error. form inside form tag. I needed rest a long time.

Many thanks anyway